# Penny that doubles in value every sec for 30 sec Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing this piece of code where you start out with 1 penny and it doubles within every second for 30 seconds. The ultimate result is 107374182.4 million dollars. I did it the simplest way I know. I have recently started coding using Python 3. How can I simply this?

```
import time

penny = 0.1

time.sleep(1)
pen1 = penny * 2
print(pen1)

time.sleep(1)
pen2 = pen1 * 2
print(pen2)

time.sleep(1)
pen3 = pen2 * 2
print(pen3)

time.sleep(1)
pen4 = pen3 * 2
print(pen4)

time.sleep(1)
pen5 = pen4 * 2
print(pen5)

time.sleep(1)
pen6 = pen5 * 2
print(pen6)

time.sleep(1)
pen7 = pen6 * 2
print(pen7)

time.sleep(1)
pen8 = pen7 * 2
print(pen8)

time.sleep(1)
pen9 = pen8 * 2
print(pen9)

time.sleep(1)
pen10 = pen9 * 2
print(pen10)

time.sleep(1)
pen11 = pen10 * 2
print(pen11)

time.sleep(1)
pen12 = pen11 * 2
print(pen12)

time.sleep(1)
pen13 = pen12 * 2
print(pen13)

time.sleep(1)
pen14 = pen13 * 2
print(pen14)

time.sleep(1)
pen15 = pen14 * 2
print(pen15)

time.sleep(1)
pen16 = pen15 * 2
print(pen16)

time.sleep(1)
pen17 = pen16 * 2
print(pen17)

time.sleep(1)
pen18 = pen17 * 2
print(pen18)

time.sleep(1)
pen19 = pen18 * 2
print(pen19)

time.sleep(1)
pen20 = pen19 * 2
print(pen20)

time.sleep(1)
pen21 = pen20 * 2
print(pen21)

time.sleep(1)
pen22 = pen21 * 2
print(pen22)

time.sleep(1)
pen23 = pen22 * 2
print(pen23)

time.sleep(1)
pen24 = pen23 * 2
print(pen24)

time.sleep(1)
pen25 = pen24 * 2
print(pen25)

time.sleep(1)
pen26 = pen25 * 2
print(pen26)

time.sleep(1)
pen27 = pen26 * 2
print(pen27)

time.sleep(1)
pen28 = pen27 * 2
print(pen28)

time.sleep(1)
pen29 = pen28 * 2
print(pen29)

time.sleep(1)
pen30 = pen29 * 2
print(pen30)
```

Comment: Use a loop, or more advanced: a generator!

Comment: Couple of links that might help you. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Two additions: a penny is usually not 0.1 and you should use integers here, floats are getting inaccurate if they get larger.

Comment: With @KlausD 's point, he's implying that a float isn't required for this particular problem since you don't have to deal with decimals (assuming the number represents a cent). For further learning read about how a float is stored to see why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a loop (always remember-when writing code if some code repeats itself use a loop, or a function):

```
penny = 0.1
for i in range(30):
    time.sleep(1)
    penny *= 2
    print(penny)
```

Comment: In this case couldn't one also write 0.1 * 2 ** 30

Comment: yes of course, but I think he wants to print every step, that's why

Comment: Yes, also learning about loops first is better then to learn about a magic function.

Answer (score 1):

```
total_time = 30
pennies = 1
for i in range (total_time):
    pennies *= 2
dollars = pennies/100
print(dollars)
```